# Google Diff Charts using JSON datatable returning [all series on a given axis must be of the same data type]

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to generate a diff chart to compare two set of data using Google Visualization. (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart)

Data A:
`{"cols":[{"label":"Month","type":"string"},{"label":"Total","type":"number"},{"type":"string","role":"style","p":{"role":"style"}}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"8","f":"2014-08"},{"v":"68435.52"},{"v":"orange"}]}]}`

Data B:
`{"cols":[{"label":"Month","type":"string"},{"label":"Total","type":"number"},{"type":"string","role":"style","p":{"role":"style"}}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"9","f":"2014-09"},{"v":"67348.25"},{"v":"orange"}]}]}`

But I keep getting this error whenever I draw the chart:

`all series on a given axis must be of the same data type`

Here is my code:

```
var dataA = new google.visualization.DataTable(data1);
var dataB = new google.visualization.DataTable(data2);

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

var diffData = chart.computeDiff(dataA, dataB);

 chart.draw(diffData);
```

--
EDIT:

**jsFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/9svvm1rj/

Comment: A working example on something like plunker, codepen, or jsfiddle would be helpful.  Just looking at your code I suspect it is because your data objects have number values in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with my JS I found out that the "style" column (`{"type":"string", "role":"style"}`) is causing the problem.

I don't know if this is a bug on Google Chart API or it is a feature that is yet to be implemented so for now I removed the style and it worked.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb795hyx/